# Why probability of intersection with sufficient statistic can always be reduced?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Suppose we have a random vector $X= (X_1, \cdots, X_n)$ where each $X_i \sim F_{\theta}$ for some distribution $F$ parametrized by ${\theta}$. Suppose we want to show directly from the definition, not using Factorization theorem, that $T(X)$ is a sufficient statistic. Then to show so we should show $\mathbb{P}_{\theta}(X \mid T(X)=t )$ is independent of $\theta$ so we write the following

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\mathbb{P}_{\theta}(X \mid T(X)=t )=
\frac{\mathbb{P}_{\theta}(X_1=x_1, \cdots, X_n=x_n \quad \text{and} \quad T(x)=t)}{\mathbb{P}_{\theta}(T(x)=t)}
\end{equation}
where $x= (x_1, \cdots, x_n)$ is a realization of $X$. We always write the following
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}_{\theta}(X_1=x_1, \cdots, X_n=x_n \quad \text{and} \quad T(x)=t)=
\begin{cases}
0 \quad \quad \quad \text{if} \quad T(x) \neq t \\
\mathbb{P}_{\theta}(X_1=x_1, \cdots, X_n=x_n) \quad \text{if} \quad T(x) =t
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Therefore we have the following
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\mathbb{P}_{\theta}(X \mid T(X)=t )=
\frac{\mathbb{P}_{\theta}(X_1=x_1, \cdots, X_n=x_n)\text{1}\{T(x)=t\}}{\mathbb{P}_{\theta}(T(x)=t)}
\end{equation}

> Can you please tell me **Rigorously** why we can always get $(2)$ from $(1)$ and why the second case always holds?

Comment: For (2), it is better to also multiply the RHS by $1\{T(x) = t\}$. In the same equation, writing $\mathbb P_\theta(X = x \mid T(X) = t)$ for the LHS is better as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event $\big[ X_1=5\ \&\ X_2 = 7\ \&\ X_1+X_2=12\big]$ is the same as the event $\big[ X_1 = 5\ \&\ X_2=7\big].$ Either of those events occurs if and only if the other occurs.